# How to manipulate timestamp columns in Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I have a table with a `timestamp` column, and I'd like to manipulate the values of that column. For instance, I need to do something along the line:

`UPDATE mytable SET datetimecolumn = datetimecolumn + 10mins`

How is it done in Apache Cassandra?

**UPDATE**: The answer seems to be "you can't". But the selected answer is the closest we can get apparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can query similar this one, only if the data type is counter.**

**Using Counter :**

> A counter is a special column used to store a number that is changed in increments. For example, you might use a counter column to count the number of times a page is viewed.
>
> Define a counter in a dedicated table only and use the counter data type. You cannot index, delete, or re-add a counter column. All non-counter columns in the table must be defined as part of the primary key.

Example :

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
   pk1 int PRIMARY KEY,
   datetimecolumn counter
);
```

Here you have to use datetimecolumn value in millisecond.
For the first time, you have to use update query with the time in millisecond value let's say 1487686182403

```
UPDATE mytable SET datetimecolumn = datetimecolumn + 1487686182403 where pk1 = 1
```

Now mytable with pk = 1 contains datetimecolumn = 1487686182403 value.

If you want to increment datetimecolumn by 10mins (600000 millisecond)

```
UPDATE mytable SET datetimecolumn = datetimecolumn + 600000 where pk1 = 1
```

Source : https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_counter_t.html

Answer (score 1):

*read-before-write* is a anti-pattern in cassandra. You have manipulate the value at client side and update as usual;

In other words: you have to search (select) the value, do changes (increment by 10mins) and update at cassandra the new value.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your answer. Could you please elaborate.